# Replace onsubmit with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit

I have these code below :

```
<form name="submissions" action="/" onsubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=900,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" target="foo" method="post">
.......
<input type="submit" id="printbtn" name="printbtn" value="Print" />
<input type="submit" id="editbtn" name="editbtn" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

*** Edited ***

the window.open should only happens when the Print button is clicked.
I want to remove onsubmit() event and do it with jQuery. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this work?

```
$('form[name="submissions"]').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     // Do other stuff   
});
```

UPDATE: Actually, try this out...

```
$(function(){
    $('form[name="submissions"]').removeAttr('onsubmit')
        .submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
                    // This cancels the event...
        });
    // This should fire your window opener...
    $('#printbtn').click(function(){
        window.open('', 'foo', 'width=900,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    })

});
```

Should remove the onsubmit, and prevent the form from submitting...

Comment: Thank you But I missed something in my question.Please review my question again.

Comment: Updated my answer... How now?

Comment: It open a new window but the window is blank,it seems the form isn't  submitted

Comment: I found the problem.The preventDefault should not be used. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('form[name=submission]').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //your code
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you But I missed something in my question.Please review my question again.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#btn").on('click', function(e) {
  window.open('', 'foo', 'width=900,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
  e.preventDefault();

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the onsubmit function then I think this should do the trick.

```
$("form[name='submissions']").attr('onsubmit', '');
```